# How to authorize client for HERE's Fuel API?

Tags: json, api, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am trying to extract some JSON data from the api found on HERE: https://fuel-v2.cit.cc.api.here.com/fuel/stations.json.

I have generated an OAuth2 Token and I was able to use it to authenticate other HERE requests but when I try to authorize the Fuel API with this same token. It gives me this report:

Type is Forbidden and it says these credentials do not authorize access

[image]

I have tried using other authentication methods from HERE including the App Code authentication but that has since been deprecated.

Comment: Same here @Here Support. Could you please help?